# Circle isn't being drawn upon mouse click (pygame)

Tags: python, pygame, mouseevent, draw, geometry

I want to draw a circle at the mouse position when i click the mouse but it is not working. It is inside the while loop like I was told to do by the internet but it still isn't working. Can someone please help. Thanks.

```
def run_game():
    screen_height = 670
    screen_width = 1270
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
    screen.fill((10,10,30))
    running = True

    pygame.display.flip()
    while running:
        planet_color = (255,0,0)
        planet_radius = 100
        circ = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                pygame.draw.circle(screen, planet_color, (circa), planet_radius, 0)
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    running = False


run_game()
```

Answer (score 1):

You made a typo when coding

```
pygame.draw.circle(screen, planet_color, (circa), planet_radius, 0)
```

I think you meant to type:

```
pygame.draw.circle(screen, planet_color, (circ), planet_radius, 0)
```

Always check the error log: it should tell you where you made a mistake

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `pygame.display.flip()` to update the display and of course fix the `circ`/`circa` typo.

Some suggestions: Add a `pygame.time.Clock` to limit the frame rate.

Mouse events have a `pos` attribute, so you can replace the `circ` variable with `event.pos`.

The `planet_color` and `planet_radius` can be defined outside of the while loop.

```
planet_color = (255,0,0)
planet_radius = 100
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, planet_color, event.pos, planet_radius)
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                running = False

    pygame.display.flip()  # Call flip() each frame.
    clock.tick(60)  # Limit the game to 60 fps.
```